# transform text to uppercase in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Can I convert text to uppercase when drawing it into the canvas tag?

`textTransform="uppercase"` doesn't seem to work, and the canvas tag doesn't inherit CSS `text-transform:uppercase`.

The text is coming from a variable whose contents I don't have control over, so I can't just write it uppercase to start with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by don't have control over a variable.

`fillText(variable.toUpperCase(), x, y)` is what you'd do.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! That worked. Never seen that before!

I merely meant I'm not the one providing the content of the variable, and the person that is needs to enter it lowercase for other purposes. I guess I could have converted it to uppercase first, but that seemed a bit long-winded.

Thanks for your help.